# Apache add Content of a Link to response

Tags: apache

I want to know if it is possible to let apache substitue a link in the html I return to the client with the html of the site behind the link.
So instead of

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="<some link>">Link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
   // the html of the page behind the link
  </body>
</html>
```

I can´t use javascript or php or anything, let´s assume I only have html.
IFrames are as well no solution for my problem.

Comment: as far as I know, apache doesn't do anything like that. Question would be why don't you have PhP installed and running on your apache server ? And why is javascript not a solution (as doing HTTP request is one of the things browsers do the best...)

Comment: does "or anything" include not being able to use [SSI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html#basic)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for everyone that comes to a similar situation, Ulrich Schwarz gave a good hint with SSIs, which is in this scenario the only way that could work. However, due to cancelling the project, I was not able to validate the usage of SSI for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This can be little painful to do and might not be suitable for all cases but you can maintain a plaintext file for every html page you want to show source of and add a link to that file instead.

For eg: Instead of `<a href='somefile.html'>Click</>` do `<a href='somefile.source'>Click</>`

where somefile.source is the copy of the somefile.html. Add triple qoutes `"""` in the first and the last line of the file. I didn't try a lot of combinations but this works for fairly decent html codes.